# CSS: How to transform DIV when <li> Item of Navigation gets :hovered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I want to decorate a horizontal navigation with a `div`-element that "slides" below the navigation, depending on which `<li>` item is currently hovered.

Example:

```
li:nth-child(1):hover { transform: translateX(100px) };
li:nth-child(2):hover { transform: translateX(200px) };
li:nth-child(3):hover { transform: translateX(300px) };
li:nth-child(4):hover { transform: translateX(400px) };
```

---

**Challenge:** Until now I couldn't figure out which CSS-selector I have to use according to move the `div`. I have tried all solutions mentioned in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered), but none of them has worked yet.

---

**Example:**

```css
* { list-style-type: none; }

ul { display: flex }

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
}

.red_circle {
    display: block;
    top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(1):hover > .red_circle,
li:nth-child(1):hover + .red_circle,
li:nth-child(1):hover .red_circle,
li:nth-child(1):hover ~ .red_circle, {
    transform: translatex(400px);
}
```

```html
<container>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="red_circle"</div>
    
</container>
```

Comment: Use javascript `mouseover` event listener

Comment: @AhmadHabib: I would prefer pure CSS instead of messing around with JavaScript... :-)

Comment: You can't do exactly what you want with CSS. If you just want the same red div to slide across when any of the li elements is hovered over you could instead get sort of the same  result by putting the hover on the ul and using the CSS sibling selector. But do you want different-looking elements to slide across depending on which li element is hovered over? If so you'll need to alter the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.

If there was a way to do it, it would be in the current CSS selectors specs:

[Selectors Level 3 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors)

But to achieve this you can modify your html to put your red circle indide your `ul` tag

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

.red_circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

li:nth-child(1):hover~.red_circle {
  transform: translatex(400px);
}
```

```html
<container>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>

    <div class="red_circle"> </div>
  </ul>

</container>
```

---

**EDIT:**
After reading the [HTML 5 standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-ul-element)

> Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
> So has i said in the comment you could use `:before`pseudo element

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list-container {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  width: max-content;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

ul:hover:before {
  transform: translatex(400px);
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div class="list-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</container>
```

Comment: I think an unordered list element should have only li elements as children.

Comment: I agree on one part that in unorderd list you should have list item only but this approach does not add the circle in a `li` tag, you can also add it in a `:before` pseudo element

Comment: Actually this answer is good, but it does not completely solve the initial question. :-) Originally it was aimed to move the ```<div>``` corresponding to which ```<li>``` item is hovered... Hovering ```<li>``` no. 1 should move 100 px, hovering no. 2 should move 200 px, and so on...

Comment: Oh my bad, so i think the first answer is the most suitable for your issue :)